# Dispaly ruler and the grid in powerpoint using VSTO project

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I'm new to VSTO development.  I need to  add a ribbon menu  to Power point . And this has a tick to enable ruler and the grid in power Point Slide. Is there any inbuilt method to active those via VSTO project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the grid lines with this line of code:

```
Application.DisplayGridLines = True
```

I'm seeing a way to display the ruler.

What is the scenario for displaying the ruler? Do you want to add button to custom ribbon that displays the ruler? If this is the case, you could use RibbonXML to include the built-in "Show Ruler" checkbox in custom ribbon.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa942866.aspx

Comment: gird is working fine now. In my Ribbon there is a check box to show the ruler. but im not using Ribbon XMl at this moment